# выезжающая View при скролле UICollectionView вверх по аналогии с Google

Tags: ios, swift4

Всем привет. 
Подскажите как можно реализовать поведение верхнего бара как в Гугл?
Нужно со своими вьюшками сделать такое же поведение как у при скролле вниз все прятаться, при скроле вверх - появляться сначала поиск а потом уже остальная вьюшка.
Это все должно быть как одно целое с CollectionView.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен любым подсказкам касательно реализации данного поведения

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [этой](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar/) библиотекой. Поддержка UIView описана в  разделе [Followers](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar#followers).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]